# IIS 7 URL Rewrite match for particular URL

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

I would like to match exactly https://internet.dev.local/**KYR** url (without / into end) and redirect or rewrite to https://internet.dev.local/**KYR/** (with /).

I am trying the following rule but it matches other URLs as well e.g. **https://internet.dev.local/KYR/Admin/Form/Default.aspx?signup=false**, which is wrong.

so how can I achieve this?

```
<rule name="Static redirect" patternSyntax="ExactMatch" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="https://internet.dev.local/KYR" negate="true" />
        <conditions>
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="/Login/?ReturnUrl=/Member/KYR/" redirectType="Permanent" />
      </rule>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to test the host and protocol you have to put it in the conditions, not in the global rule.
Following your example, it would be as follow:

```
<rule name="test" patternSyntax="ExactMatch" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="KYR" />
  <action type="Redirect" url="/KYR/" redirectType="Permanent" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="internet.dev.local" />
    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="on" />
  </conditions>
</rule>
```

I have changed the `url` in the action because your question says:
`redirect or rewrite to https://internet.dev.local/KYR/ (with /).`

**EDIT:**
To get it to work on any host (with or without SSL), just remove the conditions:

```
<rule name="test" patternSyntax="ExactMatch" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="KYR" />
  <action type="Redirect" url="/KYR/" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

Comment: doesn't work, doesn't redirect url https://internet.dev.local/KYR to https://internet.dev.local/KYR /

Comment: Well I tested it and when I reach `internet.dev.local/KYR` it sends me to `internet.dev.local/KYR/`. Isn't that what you want to do?

Comment: work on my machine but doesn't work on server. how i can change to look for kyr (nothing after kyr e.g. hostname/kyr) so i don't need to change web.config for every environment (means host name could be anything)

Comment: I have edited my answer: you can simply remove the conditions and it should work

Comment: i don't know why doesn't work on server its going straight to signup page rather than redirecting to kyr /

Comment: I just tested with a closed website requiring authentication and it still goes through.

Comment: after changing its match following url as well, which i don't want to match. e.g. https://internet.dev.local/KYR/Admin/Form/Default.aspx?signup=false

Comment: If you have `<match url="KYR" />` and `patternSyntax="ExactMatch"` it shouldn't be the case...

Comment: kyr is the application under internet.dev.local site. Is it the reason its doesn't work for me?

Comment: It still goes to the signup page? Does your kyr app access require authentication? If you go directly to internet.dev.local/kyr/ (with the trailing `/`) what do you get?

Comment: if request is internet.dev.local/kyr/ (with tralling /) than it goes to default page of kyr application, which is correct. But if request is without / (internet.dev.local/kyr) than its redirect by KYR form authentication means going on signup page rather than look after by IIS rules. I would like to hit default page with or without / as end of request.

Comment: What if in the action you replace `url="/KYR/"` with `url="KYR/"`? Are you in any case here (under the `KNOWN ISSUES AND CHANGES` section): http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-applications-on-iis/provide-url-rewriting-functionality

Comment: Can you try using the [Failed Request Tracing tool](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules) and post the result?